# Move PHP binaries to another server

Tags: php, package, libraries, binaries, rhel6

I have a PHP installation that I did by compiling from the sources on a RHEL6 server.
All is fine and working.

My question is:

Can I copy the "php installation" to another server and have it run without compiling on that other server ?

*I already did, however, it's missing libraries in /usr/lib64, etc... Do I just copy them one by one over ? Or i RE-Download all the mcrypt modules and so on with YUM.... (Il would like to not do that and juste have a php package of my own to deploy on other servers...)

Or could I just do a in house php (my own compiled one) packaged in a RPM ?

Thanks !

Comment: Also, if some one could just help me build a RPM of my PHP Compiled version. That would be great. I found this doc, but only does it for PHP-fpm, that I do not want... http://blog.digitalstruct.com/    Still interesting blogpost...